# How to get session list from opentok java sdk?

Tags: opentok, tokbox

I want to get session list from java SDK but when I look API DOC, I see anything related it. This is a basic trivial case, I do not believe that not exist. 
Link api doc java : https://tokbox.com/developer/sdks/java/reference/

Answer (score 0):

Currently there's no way to list sessions using any of the SDKs or REST API. You will have to keep track of them on your server yourself as you create the sessions. The most common pattern is to store the session IDs in your data store and map it to some sort of meeting ID. How you do this is up to and will depend on your use case, eg. how long you want the session to live and which if your users you want to be able to join the session.

Comment: Thanks for your response!